# wp-env docker issue connecting to mysql

Tags: mysql, linux, wordpress

I get a db error when i run `wp-env logs`..

```
$ wp-env logs
wordpress_1        | 
wordpress_1        | MySQL Connection Error: (2006) MySQL server has gone away
wordpress_1        | [25-Oct-2020 12:12:33 UTC] PHP Warning:  Packets out of order. Expected 0 received 1. Packet size=71 in Standard input code on line 22
wordpress_1        | [25-Oct-2020 12:12:33 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysqli::__construct(): Error while reading greeting packet. PID=70 in Standard input code on line 22
wordpress_1        | [25-Oct-2020 12:12:33 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2006): MySQL server has gone away in Standard input code on line 22
```

so I reset MySQLd with some new variables in /etc/mysql/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]                                                                                       |
# 8 hours                                                                                      |
wait_timeout = 28800                                                                           |
# 8 hours                                                                                      |
interactive_timeout = 28800                                                                    |
max_allowed_packet = 256M
```

then restart mysql

```
service mysql restart
```

but that doesn't seem to fix it. I don't have a lot of mem on this computer. could that be an issue ... ?

```
# free -h
total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
|Mem:           1.9G        1.2G        129M        173M        534M        339M
#                                                                                              |Swap:          1.3G        1.2G         97M
```

does anyone have any ideas ?

this is my .wp-env.json file ...

```
{
"core": ".",
"themes": [
    "./wp-content/themes/s-child"
],
"config": {
    "WP_DB_HOST":"127.0.0.1"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So basically I included

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

in /etc/mysql/my.cnf above. It seems that the docker container can't connect to MySQL on localhost by design. This allows mysqld to connect to the docker container on any IP.

Then make sure that your MySQL root user can also connect from non-localhost IP's...

Login to MySQL from the Linux cli ...  Check if root is available from '%' (any IP)...

```
mysql> SELECT host, user, password FROM user WHERE host = '%';
+------------------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| host             | user | password                                  |
+------------------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| %                | root | *xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx |
+------------------+------+-------------------------------------------+
```

If you don't see above then run to allow all access ...

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Then restart MySQL ..

```
service mysql restart
```

Then check to see where the MySQL service is bound ..

```
dara@dara-HP-Stream-Laptop-11-y0XX:~$ sudo netstat -tupan | grep mysql
[sudo] password for dara: 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      916/mysqld
```

Or since MySQL is configured to run on localhost only by default. You could comment out the following in my.cnf

```
# bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

Which takes care of the MySql connection error issue.

Then since I'm running a wp-env docker container to create a Wordpress image. I run a

```
wp-env clean all
```

Which cleans the Wordpress databases ... then I do a

```
wp-env --update --debug start
```

To create a Wordpress docker container with access to MySQL

If that doesn't work, then try a

```
wp-env destroy && wp-env start
```

Warning: wp-env destroy is the last resort and deletes docker containers, volumes, and networks associated with the WordPress environment and removes local files.

However, I had no docker containers, volumes or networks i wanted to preserve. This worked for me.